# Unreal 4 - Vehicle from scratch - Vehicle does not move

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4

Anyone can help me with U4 Vehicle basic project ?

(I cant get any help anywhere on unreal forums)

here is the link to the zipped porject(+-1mb)
https://answers.unrealengine.com/storage/attachments/221022-blenderimportvehicle.zip

no matter what I do I cant get the car moving

I enabled the inputs in the car BP, and in the project BP, I've set the car pawn to be automaticaly possessed...still nothing

please help me on this one, it's my first shot with unreal and so far this AAA engine seems really buggy (I use v 4.18)

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I am a bit disapointed by the genral attitude, If one considers this a bad question just say so

I found a solution anyway

my scales were not right in blender, I had to set the units to cm then it worked fine